# How to store data in multiple tables using Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've Module that have multiple media. I want to use eloquent to store data in three table. My tables are as follow

users, DrivingSession, Media 
,DrivingSession model contains the user_id and Media model have the driving_session_id. I want to store DrivingSession image/videos created by specific user inside the Media model.My model functions are.

Users.php

```php
public function drivingsessions(){
    return $this->hasmany(DrivingSession::class);
}
```

DrivingSession.php

```php
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function Medias(){
     return $this->hasMany(Media::class);
}
```

Media.php

```php
public function drivingSession(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(DrivingSession::class);
}
```

I want to store user_id for reference in DrivingSessions table and the attached Media to Medias table. how can I do this ?

Comment: ?? `blongsToMany` ?? Spelling error

Comment: i've edited this.

Comment: you can use attach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only 1 user per driving session then it should be a BelongsTo relationship.

```
public function user()
{
 return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Providing that you have setup your db table with a user_id you should then be able to run

```
$user->drivingsessions()->save($driving_session);
```

And that will automagically populate the user_id column in the drivingsession.

You would do a similar thing on media and again I think it is more likely you want belongsTo rather than belongsToMany;

```
$driving_session->medias()->save($media);
```

If you are creating the resource then you can use the below

```
$driving_session = $user->drivingsessions()->create([
    'title' => $request->input('title'),
]);
```

Then you can use the captured resource to update the media

```
$driving_session->medias()->create([
    'media' => $request->input('media');
])
```

Comment: so it'd be something like this ?  
$user = User::find(1);
$drvsess =  new DrivingeSession();
$drvess->titel = $request->title;
$user->drivingSession()->save($drvess);

$media = new Media();
$drvsess ->media()->save($request->media);

is that something like this ???

Comment: Yes, but if the media is from an upload then you will have to process the file first, if its a link then it should work like that.  Also if creating then there is a short cut, I will amend my answer.

Comment: No Problem @Muhammed, don't forget to mark the answer as correct.